# Unsure how to name this problem: Multiple outcomes lead to multiple echo's

Tags: bash

First of all, I am new here and I am a total n00b in bash scripting so I hope I won't mess up this first question of mine. This all has to do with reading out the data of a save game file, it's part of a larger script where I can select a character and keep the game char selection menu clean as well as makes backups on exiting the game. This will add the information on the character to the selection menu. (Diablo II LoD and more than 40 characters doesn't always do well when searching for them in the char selection menu)

I have looked for answers before signing up to Stackoverflow, but I only see answers where there are only two outcomes: Yes or No, 1 or 1, etc. From this I have tried with the below script, but yeah... doesn't work that way. :(

**The Script:**

```
#!/bin/bash
d2s=barfive.d2s
charclass="$(xxd -u -p -l1 -s 40 "$d2s")"

if [ "$charclass" == "00" ]; then
    echo "Amazon";
     else [ "$charclass" == "01" ];
    echo "Sorceress";
         elif [ "$charclass" == "02" ];
        echo "Necromancer";
         elif [ "$charclass" == "03" ];
        echo "Paladin";
         else [ "$charclass" == "04" ];
        echo "Barbarian";
         else [ "$charclass" == "05" ];
        echo "Druid";
         else [ "$charclass" == "06" ];
        echo "Assassin";
fi
```

**What I want to do:**

Basically the outcome range from 00 to 06, each having a different outcome as described above, and I want to echo the correct value to the list. So if the outcome of the xxd command is 00, Amazon should be the output. If 06, Assassin should be the output.

**The error it gives now:**

```
./test.sh: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
./test.sh: line 26: `             elif [ "$charclass" == "02" ];'
```

Comment: Please don't change titles of posts, especially not post about this in another post ;) Right now you are untruthful as I merely stated, in that other post, (Revamped Post) and clearly explained what my questions were and why I changed it. I never said Solved or any of the sorts. Please revert it back as it was.

Comment: Huh? The link in the other post will work regardless of the title of this one. I also don't understand what you are trying to say I am untruthful about. The [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63502016/revisions) clearly shows exactly what I reverted. The other question (I guess you mean https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63509884/menu-issues-read-data-from-selected-save-file-and-menu-choices) is a separate topic, which is best discussed there.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use `case` for that

```
case $charclass in
    00) echo "Amazon";;
    01) echo "Sorceress";;
    02) echo "Necromancer";;
    03) echo "Paladin";;
    04) echo "Barbarian";;
    05) echo "Druid";;
    06) echo "Assassin";;
     *) echo "no match";;
esac
```

Or using an array

```
chars=(
    Amazon
    Sorceress
    Necromancer
    Paladin
    Barbarian
    Druid
    Assassin
)

echo ${chars[charclass]}
```

Comment: I will have to look in the case part of this.
As for the array, I just tried it but on any char it shows the top one only: Amazon.

Comment: Maybe charclass isn't changing?

Comment: It is on my end. I choose a different char and it sticks to Amazon. The case works partially. It shows this outcome. Always no match above charclass.

no match
Sorceress

Comment: Looks like `charclass="$(xxd -u -p -l1 -s 40 "$d2s")"` gives values not in `0[1-6]` template.

Comment: Check it by echoing charclass `echo $charclass`

Comment: Aye, works now. ^_^ Thanks. And sorry for being extremely new on this. I'll learn from it.

Comment: charclass="$(xxd -u -p -l1 -s 40 "$d2s")"   Yes it does.  00, 01, 02, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions have been given and both work equally good.

@ivan

```
case $charclass in
    00) echo "Amazon";;
    01) echo "Sorceress";;
    02) echo "Necromancer";;
    03) echo "Paladin";;
    04) echo "Barbarian";;
    05) echo "Druid";;
    06) echo "Assassin";;
     *) echo "no match";;
esac
```

---

@Sparrow and @hotoku

```
   #!/bin/bash
   d2s=barfive.d2s
   charclass="$(xxd -u -p -l1 -s 40 "$d2s")"
   
   if [ "$charclass" == "00" ]; then
       echo "Amazon";
            elif [ "$charclass" == "02" ]; then
           echo "Necromancer";
            elif [ "$charclass" == "03" ]; then
           echo "Paladin";
            elif [ "$charclass" == "04" ]; then
           echo "Barbarian";
            elif [ "$charclass" == "05" ]; then
           echo "Druid";
            elif [ "$charclass" == "06" ]; then
           echo "Assassin";
            else [ "$charclass" == "01" ];
       echo "Sorceress";
   fi
```

So thanks to all three. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You should replace all `else` but last one to `elif`, like this:

```
if [ "$charclass" == "00" ]; then
    echo "Amazon";
elif [ "$charclass" == "01" ]; then
     echo "Sorceress";
elif [ "$charclass" == "02" ]; then
     echo "Necromancer";
elif [ "$charclass" == "03" ]; then
     echo "Paladin";
elif [ "$charclass" == "04" ]; then
     echo "Barbarian";
elif [ "$charclass" == "05" ]; then
     echo "Druid";
elif [ "$charclass" == "06" ]; then
     echo "Assassin";
else
    echo "no match"
fi
```

Comment: Hi, First of all thanks for the fast answer. I changed all but last one to elif, same error. ./test.sh: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
./test.sh: line 26: `             elif [ "$charclass" == "02" ];'

Comment: sorry I can not reproduce the error in my environment .

Comment: Now it works. Awesome! So each elif/else should be followed by a then. ^_^ Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is incorrect, it should be.

```
if <expression>; then
        <commands>
    elif <expression>; then
        <commands>
    else
        <commands>
    fi
```

Your code should be something as below.

```
   #!/bin/bash
   d2s=barfive.d2s
   charclass="$(xxd -u -p -l1 -s 40 "$d2s")"
   
   if [ "$charclass" == "00" ]; then
       echo "Amazon";
            elif [ "$charclass" == "02" ]; then
           echo "Necromancer";
            elif [ "$charclass" == "03" ]; then
           echo "Paladin";
            elif [ "$charclass" == "04" ]; then
           echo "Barbarian";
            elif [ "$charclass" == "05" ]; then
           echo "Druid";
            elif [ "$charclass" == "06" ]; then
           echo "Assassin";
            else [ "$charclass" == "01" ];
       echo "Sorceress";
   fi
```

Comment: Thank you! Got it working. ^_^ Also I understand it better now and realized my mistake.